# Angular form validation is not working

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have the following form :

UPDATE

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form-profile.html">
            <form id="f1" name="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="formData.name"  ng-class="submitted ? 'ng-dirty' : ' ' " required autofocus> 
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="form.name.$dirty || form.name.$invalid">Name is required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="formData.email" ng-class="submitted ? 'ng-dirty' : ' '" required autofocus>
                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="f1.email.$dirty && f1.email.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show="f1.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Cellphone">Mobil nr.</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Cellphone" ng-model="formData.Cellphone" ng-class="submitted ? 'ng-dirty' : ' '" required autofocus>
                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="f1.Cellphone.$dirty && f1.Cellphone.$invalid">
                        <span ng-show="f1.Cellphone.$error.required">Cellphone is required.</span>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Adresse</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" ng-model="formData.address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col col-33 col-offset-67">
                    <a ui-sref="front.form.organisation" class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right  button-energized .col-offset-50">
                        Next
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </script>
```

When I press next I want the form to disable the next button and show me the errors.

I have tried with name so far and I did not get the errors.

Thank you

Comment: do you wrap your code inside form element?

Comment: Yes .I will update now

Comment: You want to submit form by keyboard enter, right? because I dont see submit button in your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see demo below

```
ng-show="f1.name.$dirty <-- f1 that's form name not id
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {




});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <form name="f1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="formData.name" required autofocus>

        <span style="color:red" ng-show="f1.name.$dirty  && f1.name.$invalid">Name is required</span>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you check my update. But this code <span style="color:red" ng-show="f1.name.$dirty  && f1.name.$invalid">Name is required</span>
does not get executed

Comment: @besa use form name not id in your ng-show directive

Comment: I do that and still the same

Comment: @Besa it will be shown when user type in somthing and delete after do you want to message shown on page load ?

Comment: Can you check my update and let me know if I can make the validation when I press Next . Thank you so much

Comment: That is what I want but can I do the validation when I click on Next button?

Comment: I see it works there.Let me apply it on my code and see

Comment: I made it work, but I have one more thing. I want to disable the next button if the boxes are not filled

Comment: @Besa oh Dear please see here http://jsbin.com/baqovoxeru/1/edit?html,css,js,output you can add ng-class="{'cssDisabled':form.$invalid}" to your a tag and css class .cssDisabled {
  color:red;
     pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}

Comment: Sorry I asked too many question. I know to make it invalid in that way but the problem in this case will be with the feedback. How will the user know whats the problem. The required fields now are disabled

Comment: I figured it out how. Thank you so much

Comment: When the form is disabled the next button only changes the color it does not get disabled. Which in my case it moves to the other state :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73174/discussion-between-sylwester-and-besa).